# React Typescript: Configure router to allow username based URL's without conflicting with other routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I want to view I users profile on a URL like `www.domain.com/<userName>` I want to load `ShowProfile` Now I can make sure that  `terms` is not a username but if I browse to `www.domain.com/terms` I don't want to load `ShowProfile` but instead I want to load `Terms`.

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/layout';
import { Dispatch, Global, InitialState, Reducer } from './globalState';
import { ConfirmEmail } from './routes/confirmEmail';
import { Home } from './routes/home';
import { NotFound } from './routes/notFound';
import { Profile } from './routes/profile';
import { Terms } from './routes/terms';
import { ShowProfile } from './routes/showProfile';
import { ResetPassword } from './routes/resetPassword';

const Router: React.FC = () => {
  const [global, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, InitialState);
  return (
    <Dispatch.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>
      <Global.Provider value={{ global }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route
            render={({ location }) => (
              <Layout location={location}>
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                  <Route exact path='/:userName' component={ShowProfile} /> //<<== I want to view I users profile on a URL like this but the other routes break
                  <Route exact path='/terms' component={Terms} />                  
                  <Route exact path='/my/profile' component={Profile} />
                  <Route exact path='/confirm-email/:confirmationCode' component={ConfirmEmail} />
                  <Route exact path='/reset-password/:resetPassword' component={ResetPassword} />
                  <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
              </Layout>
            )}
          />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Global.Provider>
    </Dispatch.Provider>
  );
};

export { Router };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
<Switch location={location}>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route exact path='/terms' component={Terms} />                  
  <Route exact path='/my/profile' component={Profile} />
  <Route exact path='/confirm-email/:confirmationCode' component={ConfirmEmail} />
  <Route exact path='/reset-password/:resetPassword' component={ResetPassword} />
  <Route path='/:userName' component={ShowProfile} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
<Switch>
```

And do not forget to disallow register usernames that match routes

Comment: You were right, it matches from top to bottom, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should change the path?

```
'/:userName' => '/users/:userName'
```

and you won't see any problem with usernames like: terms, confirm-email, reset-password, other routes

But if you want your way you can try to use state, just my thoughts below:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />

{global.isUserRoute ?
    <Route exact path='/:userName' component={ShowProfile} /> //<<== I want to view I users profile on a URL like this but the other routes break
    :
    <>
        <Route exact path='/terms' component={Terms} />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
        // single routes...
    </>
}

// ...other specific routes with more then one slash                  
<Route exact path='/my/profile' component={Profile} />
<Route exact path='/confirm-email/:confirmationCode' component={ConfirmEmail} />
<Route exact path='/reset-password/:resetPassword' component={ResetPassword} />
<Route component={NotFound} />
```

For example, You can change isUserRoute = true when you fetch user profile and isUserRoute = false in componentWillUnmount

Comment: Yes this would be one option but I really like having a simple /<userName> URL structure, much like twitter et al

Comment: @Bill, You can try to use state, I added some info about it